# Disable firefox Remember password windows in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, firefox

I want to login in **firefox** without remember password prompt that cant save username and password.
i used autocomplete= off but dont work in firefox

```
<form autocomplete="off">
 <input id="username" type="text" runat="server" autocomplete="off"/>
 <input id="pass" type="password" runat="server" autocomplete="off"/>
```

please help me :((

Comment: you should use `autocomplete="off"` this way. have you tried this way in the form tag?

Answer (score 0):

you can do another thing-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){                                               
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("input#passfld").attr("type","password");
    },10);
});
</script>
```